# How to change version in assembly (with enabled EF CodeFirst migrations) correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

There is an assembly (1.0.0.0) with enabled migrations.
After publishing (build server) version are incremented (to 1.0.0.1) and **EF throws MetadataException**:
"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\n(0,0) : error 0004: Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blablabla' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"}

How to change version in assembly (with enabled EF CodeFirst migrations) correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer, right click on your project (Not solution) --> click on properties --> in application tab --> click on assembly infornation.

There you can change the assembly version.

Comment: I know how to change version for assembly. I need to make it so that EF worked correctly.